# Trying to update my laptop from 12.04 to 13.10 but failed to fetch

Tags: 12.04, updates

I'm a noob when it comes to Ubuntu because i usually have a guy that helps me with my needs. But he currently isn't available and i recently fixed this laptop with 2 years of no updates and no log in. Now every time i try to update it says failed to fetch because of a network problem when i obviously have all 4 bars on my WiFi and things in the background are working fine. Not only that but these other system problems i have lead back to me needing to update when i cannot. I've tried `sudo apt-get update` and have fixed other system errors but when i try to it says that some files failed to update.

Answer (score 0):

You are going from 12.04LTS (Long Term Support) to 13.10 which is not the normal upgrade path for long term support. Is this what you actually wanted? Otherwise you should consider version 14.04LTS. Another thing to consider is the system requirements for the later Ubuntu versions. Make sure your computer can handle it or consider another option like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

If you don't want to deal with network issues I would recommend to download the ISO you want, then make a bootable USB drive. Then you boot off the USB drive and install your linux distro. In this case you have the option to download the distro from another computer. If you do an internet search for "Ubuntu startup disk creator" you will find how to use that approach.